# Обработка события зажатия 2-ух клавиш одновременно

Tags: c++, qt

Как отследить зажатие 2ух клавиш одновременно в QT c++?

Например, если зажата стрелка вверх, то точка на виджете перемещается строго вверх. Если зажата стрелка влево - то строго влево. А если зажаты обе стрелки, то точка перемещается и вверх и влево (под углом 45 градусов).

Проблема выше решается, если зажимать клавиши максимально одновременно. Но возможна следующая ситуация: сначала зажимается стрелка вверх, затем, через пол секунды, зажимается стрелка влево, и по моей задумке в этот момент точка должна идти и вверх и влево, но на деле учитывается только та клавиша, которая была нажата последней (в описанном выше примере это стрелка влево) и точка идёт только влево.

```
class Widget :public QWidget {
public:
   double alpha;
   double r;
   QPointF point;

   Widget() {
      r = 20;
      point.setX(300);
      point.setY(300);
   }

   void paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event) {
      QPainter painter(this);
      painter.drawEllipse(point, r, r);
   }

   void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent* event) {
    if (event->key() == Qt::Key_Up || event->key() == Qt::Key_Left) {
        if (event->key() == Qt::Key_Up)//нажата стрелка вверх
            alpha = 90;
        if (event->key() == Qt::Key_Left)//нажата стрелка влево
            alpha = 180;
        if (/*нажаты обе стрелки*/)
            alpha = 135;
    }

    double radians = qDegreesToRadians(alpha);
    point.rx() = point.x() + cos(radians);
    point.ry() = point.y() - sin(radians);
    repaint();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

1. В обработчике события `keyPressEvent` смотрите какая клавиша была нажата и добавляйте ее в список нажатых
2. затем смотрите, какие у вас клавиши в списке и выполняйте соответствующее действие
3. В обработчике `keyReleaseEvent` удаляйте отпущенную клавишу из списка

Comment: обработчики событий `keyDown` это что? Отпускание клавиши?

Comment: в Qt есть только `keyPressEvent` и `keyReleaseEvent`

Comment: @zhukov Извините, не знаком с Qt. Обновил ответ